# Separate combination of two separate lists keeping the correspondence/dependence on each other

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have two lists of same length which have one to one correspondence:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [6,7,8,9]
```

I want to find combinations of these two lists separately. But the indices of combined elements must be the same for both lists.

For example, if I do:

```
list(itertools.combinations(a,2))
```

I may get

```
[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(3,2),(4,2),(4,3)]
```

I could've got

```
[(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)]
```

too because both are the same.

So whatever the combination I get I want the same indices combined for the second list too.

So if

```
list(itertools.combinations(a,2))
```

gives me

```
[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(3,2),(4,2),(4,3)]
```

then

```
list(itertools.combinations(b,2))
```

should give me

```
[(6,7),(6,8),(6,9),(8,7),(9,7),(9,8)]
```

or if

```
list(itertools.combinations(a,2))
```

gives me

```
[(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)]
```

then

```
list(itertools.combinations(b,2))
```

should give me

```
[(7,6),(8,6),(9,6),(7,8),(7,9),(8,9)]
```

Comment: `itertools.combinations` is deterministic so it will always give you the same result. If you're worried that `a` and `b` getting out of sync for whatever reason you can always sort by `zip`'ing beforehand.

Comment: I think you are looking for [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate combinations on the indices and then index a and b.  For instance:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [6,7,8,9]
for i0,i1 in itertools.combinations(range(len(a)), 2):
  print("{0},{1}  -->  {2},{3}".format(a[i0],a[i1],b[i0],b[i1]))


1,2  -->  6,7
1,3  -->  6,8
1,4  -->  6,9
2,3  -->  7,8
2,4  -->  7,9
3,4  -->  8,9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the source code to tell you that it's working from the index of the list, not the value of the list.  So while the output of combinations will always be the same for the same list - reversing the order of the list would obviously give you a different output for combinations.

Why not sort your list as you pass it in so that they are always in increasing numeric order, thereby sort of solving the problem.

```
a = [4,3,2,1]

list(combinations(a,2))
[(4, 3), (4, 2), (4, 1), (3, 2), (3, 1), (2, 1)]

list(combinations(sorted(a),2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Answer (score 1):

From the official python itertools [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

"Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order."

So for a sorted list, the order will always be identical, starting from the first value.

Comment: yeah actually it always returns an ordered list for a sorted input list but the problem is that i can't sort the list. Anyways thanks for help i have my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) instead of [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). Here is a possible implementation that will save a bit of time by computing the permutations a single time:

```py
import itertools

def isomorphic_permutations(*arrays, **kwargs):
    arrays_shape = len(arrays[0])
    if any(len(a) != arrays_shape for a in arrays):
        raise ValueError("All input arrays should have the same size.")
    permutations = list(itertools.permutations(range(arrays_shape), **kwargs))
    for array in arrays:
        yield ((array[x], array[y]) for x, y in permutations)
```

The kwarg `r` is used for building the permutation with `itertools.permutations(iterable, r=None)`. This corresponds to the permutations lengths. Here is how you could use this function:

```py
a = [7,6,8]
b = [6,7,8]
for permutation in isomorphic_permutations(a, b, r=2):
    print(list(permutation))
```

Which will output:

```py
[(7, 6), (7, 8), (6, 7), (6, 8), (8, 7), (8, 6)]
[(6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 6), (7, 8), (8, 6), (8, 7)]
```

Notice how the inversion of `6` and `7` is repercuted on the output permutations.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen it suggested but can't you solve it by picking from both at once.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [6,7,8,9]

from itertools import combinations

list( combinations(zip(a,b),2))
```

This yields:

```
[((1, 6), (2, 7)),
 ((1, 6), (3, 8)),
 ((1, 6), (4, 9)),
 ((2, 7), (3, 8)),
 ((2, 7), (4, 9)),
 ((3, 8), (4, 9))]
```

You can see they match across the lists.